# problem using lint in switch - case with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

I am new in using "lint"

```
case 'up':
   index > 0 ? index-- : 0; break;
```

I have a pre-commit lint script, which shows the following error:
"error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

If I change the code to the long version everything is okay?

```
case 'up':
    if (index > 0) {
       index--;
    } else {
       index = 0;
    }
```

Isn't the fist code snippet not the short form of the second?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can `index` be less then zero? why not take an assignment with the coditional operator?

Comment: In the ternary, if the condition is false it doesn't do anything.

Comment: no index can't be less than zero

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an assignment to `index`:

```
index = index > 0 ? index - 1 : 0;
```

If `index` is always positive, you chould shorten it a bit to

```
index = index ? index - 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! My problem is solved. I had another error inside the code with the `index--` You are right that `index-1` is the right code